# Deleting items other than the selected ones in listview in javafx

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have been trying to delete all items except the selected items in listview in javafx. I have written the following code. It works sometimes and sometimes does not. I am not able to figure out my mistake. Any help would be appreciated !!

```
try {
    int i = 0;
    while (!listName.getItems().equals(listName.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems())) {
        if (listName.getSelectionModel().isSelected(i) == false) {
            listName.getItems().remove(i);
            i--;
        }
        i++;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your counter i?

Comment: @KeyMaker00 Should be pretty obvious: it's the index that is tested for removal. The code is supposed to iterate through the indices of the list and for every index check, if the index is selected and delete the item at index `i`, if it isn't selected.

Comment: @fabian: Exactly, so the variable should also express this intent (code smell). (+1 for your explanation)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create an array of the items to keep and use `ObservableList.setAll` to replace the whole list:

```
ListView<Character> listView = new ListView<>();
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    listView.getItems().add(c);
}
listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

Button delete = new Button("delete");
delete.setOnAction(evt -> {
    Character[] selection = listView.getSelectionModel()
            .getSelectedIndices()
            .stream()
            .sorted()
            .map(listView.getItems()::get)
            .toArray(Character[]::new);

    listView.getItems().setAll(selection);
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectAll();
});
```